# Strange angular checkbox behavior with ng-model and select/deselect all

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, checkbox

So I cannot recreate the bug (I know it's bad). The app is big/complicated, and obviously I have yet to find out what caused the bug. I want to post here to see if anyone has had a similar experience:

http://plnkr.co/edit/nsOg4QMXLwiEfic1spXF?p=preview

```
$scope.toggleState = function() {
    for (var i=0, len = $scope.services.length;i<len; i++){
        $scope.services[i].checked = $scope.selectState;
    }
  $scope.selectState = !$scope.selectState;
};
```

The bug is that after unselecting all, selecting one standard service also selects all of the premium ones. And after selecting all, unselecting one premium services also unselects all standard ones.

What could possibly trigger this? I notice that when a source is not meant to be selected, the service.checked state is still false, but the checkbox is somehow selected. ANY suggestion would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: So the linked plunker doesn't reproduce the bug?

Comment: Usability protip: "select all" doesn't work like that - you shouldn't keep a separate selectState but instead figure it out depending on whether any checkboxes are currently checked. Otherwise the user might get into a situation where they've manually checked all the boxes and click "select all/none" - and it does nothing!

Comment: @mattivirkkunen This was built by someone else and I've read about a few solutions that also attach the select state to the model and not the physical checkbox. The button works in a desired way - first select all, the select none. It's rather unhelpful that I can't reproduce the bug.

Comment: Try selecting all the checkboxes one by one by hand (not using the button) and then clicking the button. It won't do anything.

Comment: @mattivirkkunen I see what you're saying. But it's expected behavior because clicking the button defaults to select all. A more sophisticated approach would be to check if all are selected then toggle. Anyway I solved my bug today. It turns out whoever wrote the code used this checklist-model AT THE SAME TIME as ng-model so it screwed everything up: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the previous programmer had used angular checklist in addition to ng-model: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

It's still unclear how it was set up and I'm still unable to replicate the bug. But I simply took out the checklist directive, and have a ng-click listener for which service is checked/unchecked.